# fortran default precision of numbers

Tags: fortran, precision

I chose the precision in my code as :

```
 integer, parameter ::psn=selected_real_kind(15,307)
```

then I write numbers appearing in the code with `_psn`, for example :

```
  y=x/6._psn
```

I have many long expressions in code where many numbers appear in multiplications and divisions. 
  Now my question is: Is there any way to set precision of all numbers appearing in the code to be in a selected precision without explicitly specifying `_psn` everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default kind of `real` for the compiler...

[`ifort`](http://docs.notur.no/uit/files-uit/ifort-9-x-documents/ifort-9-x-nice-to-know-options):

```
-r8    Makes  default  real  and     complex variables 8 bytes long.
```

[`gfortran`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html):

```
-fdefault-real-8    Set the default real type to an 8 byte wide type.
```

Then, you can just use `1.e0` in your code...

Comment: However, one must be careful, because one of the basic assumptions of the standard, that `double precision` shall have larger precision than the default `real` may no longer hold. The program may also have asumptions about storage size of default and double precision.

Comment: Please don't do this (use switches to change default precision) - it makes your code non-portable and difficult to maintain.

Comment: @SteveLionel I agree... For my own code, I define the precision in a globally accessible module variable `cp` and write `1.e_cp`. But the OP asked for this and it's a quick way of changing the precision ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In a portable manner, **no**.

If you choose convenience and readability over portability and maintainability, you can use compiler flags to change the default kind of `REAL`, like the accepted answer says.

It is important to understand that, in doing this, some assumptions that could be made based on the standard are often broken. Here are some examples:

- *The decimal precision of the double precision real approximation method shall be greater than that of the default real method.* If you only promote `REAL`, that is probably lost, however at least in **gfortran** the commonly used flag for that end still upholds that rule:

> `-fdefault-real-8`
>
> Set the default real type to an 8 byte wide type. This option also affects the kind of non-double real constants like `1.0`. **This option promotes the default width of `DOUBLE PRECISION` and double real constants like `1.d0` to 16 bytes if possible.**

- *A nonpointer scalar object that is default integer, default real, or default logical occupies a single numeric storage unit.*
- *A nonpointer scalar object that is double precision real or default complex occupies two contiguous numeric storage units.*

These last two imply there is something called a **numeric storage unit**, which is a basic building block of storage for numeric types, and default `REAL`, `INTEGER` and `LOGICAL` variables occupy 1 of it, while default `DOUBLE PRECISION` and `COMPLEX` occupy 2 of it. Needless to say, those contracts are also probably broken when you change default kinds.

It is possible (and even probable) that the affected code does not rely on any of those anyway, and in that case it would be harmless to use such flags. However, it remains important to understand the risks.

Comment: You comment about my comment. My comment refered to at least two.compilers, cerainly not just gfortran. Also be aware that there are other flags one must be careful about, that only promote certain kinds, even in gfortran. Otherwise, this answer only repeats what is already in the accepted answer.

Comment: @VladimirF I expanded the answer and rewrote the part that referred to your comment to clear it up. I wrote this answer because I felt the question could use one that summarized the main points, even if with little more.